# DataGridView rows are readOnly after setting its data-source to a Linq to entities query

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, linq-to-entities

I have this simple function that returns a list of employee outings

```
Function LoadEmployees() As IQueryable
        Dim employeeList = From EMP In dbTables.tableOutings _
                         Select b.OutingID, b.EmployeeMaster.EmpID, b.EmployeeMaster.EmpNumber, _
                         b.EmployeeMaster.EmpName, b.DateEngaged, b.NoticeInLiue, b.TransportCalculation, b.Others
        Return employeeList
    End Function
```

And in my formLoad event am setting the above function as a DataSource to a windows forms DataGridView control like

```
Private Sub EmployeeBenefitsForm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    dgvEmployeeOutings.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgvEmployeeOutings.DataSource = LoadEmployees()

End Sub
```

The data is correctly being loaded in the Datagridview, however the problem i need a solution to is that am getting a ReadOnly datagridview. I can't edit data in any of the columns. I want the user to be able to edit data from that datagridview.

Why is the grid ReadOnly. Is it because the data is being returned from two differtent tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a very similar questions here, it could be of help [Binding Linq To Entities query results to a datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460599/binding-linq-to-entities-query-results-to-a-datagridview).

you could also check another related question and answer here [Linq-to-entities Include method doesn't load related records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973794/linq-to-entities-include-method-doesnt-load-related-records)